# How to access "current" nested state using angular ui router with state helper

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am attempting to dynamically draw a nested navigation structure using the AngularJS UI router library with StateHelper (see example JSON below).

I am struggling with finding a way to access the array of children in my nested template. Is there a way to access the state associated with the current template / controller?

I attempted using `$state.current`, but this does not work as it resolves to the same value (rightly so) at each nested level. I need to be able to access the "current" state, i.e. the one being rendered at that moment in time.

Any ideas very welcome!!

*nested.html*

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in children" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a data-ui-sref="{{tab.name}}" ng-bind-html="tab.name"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<div data-ui-view></div>
```

*Example navigation*

```
[{
    "name": "root",
    "template": "<ui-view/>",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "url": "/a",
            "templateUrl": "static/partials/nested.html",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "1",
                    "url": "/1",
                    "templateUrl": "static/partials/nested.html",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "i",
                            "url": "/i",
                            "template": "Content for root.a.1.i"
                        }, {
                            "name": "ii",
                            "url": "/ii",
                            "template": "Content for root.a.1.ii"
                        }]
                }, {
                    "name": "2",
                    "url": "/2",
                    "templateUrl": "static/partials/nested.html",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "i",
                            "url": "/i",
                            "template": "Content for root.a.2.i"
                        }, {
                            "name": "ii",
                            "url": "/ii",
                            "template": "Content for root.a.2.ii"
                        }]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "b",
            "url": "/b",
            "template": "Content for root.b"
        }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a data field named `$uiView` attached to the **ui-view** element, it contains the **view name** and the **associated** `state`. You can get the `state` like this:

```
elem.closest('[ui-view]').data('$uiView').state
```

or even

```
elem.inheritedData('$uiView').state
```

So, in your `controller`:

```
.controller('State1Ctrl', function ($state) {
  console.log(elem.closest('[ui-view]').data('$uiView').state); // state1
});
```

See if this helps you. Also using `ui-sref`, it is possible:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in children" ng-class="{ active: $state.current == 'tab.name' }">
        <a data-ui-sref='tab.name' ng-bind-html="tab.name"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here **tab.name** being assumed to contain your state.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! In my solution, I do `$element.data('$uiView').state.children` because I am setting the controller in the navigation JSON, so the data attribute is on the same element that is currently in scope.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you.